# Proof for $\sqrt{2}$, $\sqrt{3}$, $\sqrt{5}$ can never be the terms of a single arithmetic progression with non zero common difference.

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic-progressions

> Proof for $\sqrt{2}$, $\sqrt{3}$, $\sqrt{5}$ can never be the terms of a single arithmetic progression with non zero common difference.

Here is what I have tried.

Let:

$$ax +c=\sqrt{2}$$

$$bx +c=\sqrt{3}$$

$$dx +c=\sqrt{5}$$

$$\frac{\sqrt2-c}{a}=\frac{\sqrt3-c}{b}=\frac{\sqrt5-c}{d}$$

What property can I use next?

Comment: I think you'll need to roll back and go a different direction, since your final three-way equation has real solutions in $a,b,d$...

Comment: @abiessu  I think $a,b,d$  must be integers

Comment: How did you guys arrive at that conclusion? like is there a theorem?

Answer (score 4):

We have
\begin{eqnarray*}
a= \sqrt{2} \\
a+nd= \sqrt{3} \\
a+md= \sqrt{5} \\
\end{eqnarray*}
multiply the second equation by $m$, the third equation by $n$ and subtract.

We have
\begin{eqnarray*}
(m-n)\sqrt{2}  = m\sqrt{3}-n \sqrt{5}. \\
\end{eqnarray*}
Now square this equation & conclude that $\sqrt{15}$ cannot be irrational.

Comment: $\sqrt{15}$ is irrational

Comment: @bb_823 The answer is a proof by contradiction.

Comment: @preferred_anon I think there should be something like "therefore we come to contradiction" at the end just so there isn't any confusion.